# How to print compiling directory path in scons

Tags: python-2.7, scons

i am using scons
My source code in different directories.
I want to print the directory name while scons compiling the files in directory.

I want to print the directory name first and after that compiling files names.

Now am using "CCCOMSTR" variable to print the source name. as below.

```
    env['CCCOMSTR'] = "= Compiling $SOURCE"
```

It is printing the source name with directory every time.

I want the output like:

Building directory:"directory name"

= compiling "source file name"

= compiling "source file name"

Building directory:"directory name"

= compiling "source file name"

= compiling "source file name"

can anyone tell me how to do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I dont think its possible to do what you are asking for. I imagine you have noticed by now that SCons is not like make in the sense that the commands in the Makefile are executed when evaluated, and an echo in the Makefile will be seen when you expect. SCons effectively performs 2 passes: the first being to read everything from the SCons scripts into internal structures, then analyze the structures and build what needs to be built. Any prints that are in the SCons scripts will be displayed when the script is read, not when a target is built.

Perhaps a better way to do what you are already doing is with the SCons [Progress()](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/x2005.html) function.

As mentioned in the comments, the Progress() function will only display the targets while being analyzed, not while being built. You can however get the directory of each if you provide a function to the Progress() function, one of the parameters received is the node, which is actually the target, for which you can get the directory, as explained [here](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/x776.html). Here is an example:

```
def progress_function(node)
    print 'Node %s: %s' % (node, Dir(node).abspath))

Progress(progress_function)
```

Comment: `Progress` is fine, but it's important to note that it gets executed during the first SCons stage, i.e. when the script is read, not when the files are actually compiled.

Comment: @FlorianBrucker, that's a good point, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Hi Brady...thanks for your reply.
Is there any way to print the variant directory?

Comment: @SrinivasReddy, I have an idea of how to do it, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Hi Brady.. Can you tell me how to print compiling/ variant directory while compiling...